# ActiveExplorer in Outlook not showing items when Switching folder C#

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I am trying to switch the current selected folder in outlook pragmatically, but the some white colored panel or something covers the items displayed. I can only see the bottom part of the last item in the view.

My code to switch the activeExplorer folder is:

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer().CurrentFolder = MyFolder;
```

Image of final view:

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
MyFolder.Display();
```

Comment: This opens a whole new explorer but I want to use the active explorer.

Comment: You can try this:
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer().CurrentFolder = MyFolder;
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer().Activate();

Comment: I have tried this, but it does not seem to solve the problem. What could be the possible reason of this behavior?